# Как правильно создать индекс покрытия для postgresql

Tags: postgresql, index

Создаю таблицы в PostgreSql, столкнулся с проблемой, когда индекс вроде бы задан верно, но EXPLAN проходит как-будто без него, Seq Scan

Таблица

```
CREATE TABLE public.tasks
(
    task_id smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tasks_task_id_seq'::regclass),
    task_type smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 4,
    task character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    completed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    overdue boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    date_add date NOT NULL DEFAULT date(now()),
    CONSTRAINT tasks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (task_id),
    CONSTRAINT tasks_task_type_fkey FOREIGN KEY (task_type)
        REFERENCES public.tasktypes (task_type) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT tasks_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Сам индекс

```
CREATE INDEX ix_tasks_type_user_completed
    ON public.tasks USING btree
    (task_type ASC NULLS LAST, user_id ASC NULLS LAST, completed ASC NULLS LAST, overdue ASC NULLS LAST)
    INCLUDE(task_id, date_add, task)
```

И запросы

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)
UPDATE Tasks
SET Overdue = 
    CASE WHEN (task_type = 0 AND date(now()) > date(date_add + INTERVAL'1 day'))
    THEN true
    ELSE false
    END
WHERE overdue = false AND user_id = 123123 AND completed = false
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)
UPDATE Tasks
SET completed = true
WHERE user_id = 123123 AND task_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: У вас ни в одном условии поиска нет task_type. А в индексе он на первом месте, значит поиск по данному индексу может начинаться только по этому полю

Comment: То есть играет роль позиция поля в индексе?

Comment: Конечно. Вы представьте, что составили справочник крылатых выражений и отсортировали по алфавиту, сначала первое слово, потом второе и т.п. и теперь вы пытаетесь найти что либо в нем зная только второе слово. - полный перебор, начать то не с чего. Ключ индекса строится и используется точно так же, по порядку полей

Comment: Понял, тогда логично использовать только user_id, так как он используется во всех моих запросах, остальные думаю можно убрать. Спасибо!

Comment: Да, думаю его одного достаточно. остальное уже подберется перебором записей относящихся к нему. Кстати во втором запросе я бы на месте оптимизатора пошел по первичному ключу, перебор 3х значений task_id должен проходить на ура. И если он этого не делает я сильно удивлен

Comment: Сменил индекс на `(user_id) INCLUDE (task_id, task, task_type, date_add, overdue)`, но планы остались прежними(

Comment: Зачем вам include вообще? Вы понимаете как именно и когда оно используется базой? И, что важнее, у вас в таблице сколько строк? seqscan по практически пустой таблице в принципе дешевле какие индексы не делай.

Comment: Поля, перечисленные в include использую в других запросах, в которых есть фильтр по полю user_id. Таблицы только создал, возможно дело в этом

Comment: когда записей будет хотя бы 1000 тогда можете начинать смотреть планы. include будет полезен скажем если у вас средняя длина записи 1000 байт, и часто в запросах (включая списки выборки) используются лишь несколько полей. причем это должен быть не update (потому как ему все равно в запись надо лезть что бы ее изменить), а обычная выборка, например `select task_id from tab where user_id=1` может пойти по индексу и вообще не заглядывать в данные.

Comment: Как используете? Какой профиль нагрузки на таблицы? Сделаны ли соответствующие настройки автовакуума? Это всё именно к вопросу, понимаете ли вы что такое include и как может использоваться базой. Просто так без чёткого понимания зачем оно в конкретном запросе - только размер индекса раздувать и добровольно отказываться от hot update.

Comment: И не забывайте, что любой индекс замедляет запись и изменение любого поля в Include помимо изменения его в данных потребует и модификации индекса

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Отказываюсь тогда от include, ибо нет и не будет там больших записей